# Metrics for Spring Kafka Threadpool

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, micrometer

I would like to instrument the thread pool that handles consuming Kafka events using `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka`. It would be especially useful to determine the percentage of usage, so that we have an indication when we potentially are no longer able to consume all available message when they are available.

Yes, I can use the consumer lag to create an alert when we are no longer able to process all available messages, but I would like create an alert before that occurs, so we could increase the thread pool and avoid it before it happens.

I was unable to find anything useful within the docs so far. Is there a way to determine such a metric using micrometer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, [`ExecutorServiceMetrics`](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/blob/main/micrometer-core/src/main/java/io/micrometer/core/instrument/binder/jvm/ExecutorServiceMetrics.java) might be helpful.